# Precision and significant digits in reporting standard deviation

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, significant-figures

I have 4 measurements: 40.1714, 40.1718, 40.1721 and 40.1725. The calculated standard deviation is 0.00046547466812633. With which precision (number of decimals) do I report this number as "mean +/- standard deviation" and why?

Thanks

Comment: Depends of the audience and the purpose of of your research. If you are dealing with a mass of a subatomic particle, you may want to consider as many significant digits as you can genuinly gather. For economic analysis, healthcare analysis, clinical trials, two or three significant digits suffice.

Comment: The four measurements could be $\pm 0.00005$ each because we don't know further digits. I would therefore round the standard deviation so that it has the same precision as the measurements which gives $0.0005.$ The mean I would report as $40.1719$  (rounded from $40.17185$).