# How precise when reporting mean and standard deviation?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, significant-figures

Can anybody confirm that my reasoning for the incorporation of the number of decimals is correct here?

I want to calculate the area A of a rectangle with length = 13.727 m and width = 43.313 m. Suppose the error (standard deviation) S on my measurements for the area is 0.34335235 m^2.

Would it then be correct to state that A = 13.727 m * 43.313 m = 594.56 m^2 (only 2 decimals because 5 significant digits in the original data).

However, the standard deviation is apparently always reported with only 1 significant digit so S = 0.3 m^2.

Because the measurement cannot be more precise than its standard deviation, this limits the report of the value to: A = +/- S = 594.6 +/- 0.3 m^2

Thanks

Comment: *"the standard deviation is apparently always reported with only 1 significant digit"* looks dubious, especially if that digit is $1$.  Where does it come from?  Another question is whether this is the final result or whether it might used in a further calculation: do not round before the end

Comment: @Henry is read it here: http://anderson.cm.utexas.edu/AISD/SignificantDigitsAndStandardDeviation.pdf

Comment: OK- but that is where the original calculations are reasonably precise and you are only interested in the scale of error.  In other circumstances it would be bad practice: say you measured the heights of a group of people (including children) and came to an average height of $166$cm with a standard deviation of $14$cm; it would be misleading to round this to $170$cm with a standard deviation of $10$cm

Comment: @Henry Ok I get that distinction - but how does this apply to my results then?

Comment: @YoniVerhaegen : you have asked a [very similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398222/precision-and-significant-digits-in-reporting-standard-deviation) recently. To how many digits we report measured numbers is ultimately a matter of best practice. Maximum information for the reader with a minimum of overkill.